# Issue representing 8x8 dimension with 2D arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to represent an 8x8 dimension with following values:

- `[0] [1] = 1 [0] [2] = 2 [1] [1] = 1 [1] [2] = 2 [1] [3] = 3 etc.`

I made this code, but whenever I print out the array it's giving me a zero for all odd numbers e.g.

- `[5] [3] = 0 [5] [6] = 6 [5] [5] = 0 [5] [4] = 4`

```
int [] [] chessboard = new int [8][8];
for (int i = 0; i < chessboard.length; i++) {
  chessboard [i] [0] = 0;

  for (int j = 0; j < chessboard.length; j++) {
    chessboard [i] [j] = j++;
  }
}
```

Comment: You're incrementing `j` twice within your `j` loop. So you're skipping over numbers.

Comment: Use `dimension[i][j] = j;` **instead of** `chessboard[i][j] = j++;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you may not use one array's size to iterate over another, this is unsafe. Also what you want indead if storing the column index in each box (it starts at 0), qo you just need to iterate in this way by setting value `j` (and `j++` that increase the value twice with the loop one)

```
int[][] chessboard = new int[8][8]; // here all values are 0 as it's an int array
for (int i = 0; i < chessboard.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < chessboard.length; j++) {
        chessboard[i][j] = j;
    }
}
```

---

the line `chessboard[i][0] = 0;` was useless for two reasons:

- the initial values where 0
- the loop just after started at 0 so it was also setting a `0`